# WSO2 Developer Studio - Keep comments

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

Is there a way for WSO2 Dev Studio to not remove xml comments from the ESB flows/artifacts. Good commenting is a standard I would like to implement and enforce , but there is no point if they get removed. \

Example : Create a Proxy service , go to source view , enter in comment , save , close , re-open. Comment has disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with WSO2 developer studio 3.8.0 and WSO2 ESB 4.9.0.